# Public member without inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, friend

I have a base class which looks something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr_t;
  typedef std::weak_ptr<Base> wptr_t;

  enum class Type { foo, bar, baz };

  Type x;
  // ...
};
```

I'd like those internal types to be public so that I can do stuff like `Base::ptr_t my_ptr(new Base);` and so on. But if I make a new class like this...

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  // ...
};
```

unfortunately, `Derived::ptr_t` is still a Base pointer. I'd like Derived to publicly inherit `x` from Base, but not inherit `ptr_t`,`wptr_t`, or `Type`. For example

```
Derived a;
a.x = Base::Type::foo; // this should work
a.x = Derived::Type::foo; // but I want this to fail
```

Is this possible, perhaps though some magic use of `friend` or `virtual` or something like that?

Comment: Since you want to make the pointer type match the class type, I can't help thinking you should be using templates rather than inheritance.

Comment: I do want the pointer type to match the class type, but I also want the base type to exist so that it can be used as a base type. It would be nice to have a template to automatically get the pointer typedefs right for the derived types, but I haven't thought of a neat way to achieve that with a template yet - so I'd be content to just disable them completely (which is basically what this question is about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers of iammilind and Luc Danton, here's what I've come up with:

```
class Base
{
private:
  // only 'BaseClass' is allowed to derive from Base
  Base() { }
  friend class BaseClass;
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr_t;
  typedef std::weak_ptr<Base> wptr_t;

  enum class Type { foo, bar, baz };

  Type x;
  // ...
};

class BaseClass : public Base
{
private:
  // make all the raw_Base types private
  using Base::ptr_t;
  using Base::wptr_t;
  using Base::Type;
};

class Derived : public BaseClass
{
  // define as usual, and now all is well in the world.
};

// now, to test it
class Derived2 : public Base { }; // fails

Derived d;
d.x = Derived::Type::foo; // fails
d.x = Base::Type::foo; // works
// Which is exactly what I wanted.
```

As far as I can tell, the only problem with this solution is that it adds a new and potentially confusing class. The class is defined in such a way that it can't really be misused – `Base` itself cannot be derived from except by `BaseClass`, but still, `BaseClass` is an unattractive piece of namespace-clutter.

However, for the particular piece of code that I intend to use this in, I happen to be using the equivalent of `BaseClass` already to solve an unrelated problem. So this `BaseClass` technique suits my purposes just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Simply override the type:

```
class Derived {
  typedef int Type;
};
```

It will [not allow the use of](http://www.ideone.com/vnW63) `Derived::Type` (as it's private as well as `typedef`ed)

Comment: That's a good idea, but rather than writing it in every flavour of Derived class, what i might end up doing is something like this:
`class SafeBase : public Base
{
  typedef void ptr_t;
  typedef void Type;
  // etc. `
then derive from SafeBase instead of from Base.

Comment: @karadoc, yes that is a good idea. My solution is just a way to achieve the goal. Now based on need you can use it. You can also think about `protected` inheritance (if you don't want to `typedef`). (e.g. `class Derived : protected Base`

Comment: The fact that the OP uses public inheritance when deriving `Derived` from `Base` probably indicates that the OP wants to have IS-A relationship between `Derived` and `Base`. Neither some unrelated `SafeBase` nor protected inheritance fits that intent.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  // This is now private
  using Base::ptr_t;
  using Base::wptr_t;
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I think that is not the question. OP wants the `Base::Type` not to be used as `Derived::Type` anywhere (though it's legal).

Comment: @iammilind The example in the OP covers public use only.